# Return actual type Typescript

Tags: typescript

In this minimal case, I'd like to know if it is possible for `fn` to return a value with the actual type of the argument (in this example `number`).

```
const fn = (a: any) => a;

typeof fn(0) //=> any
```

I know this could be done by adding an explicit generic type to `fn`, but I am looking for suggestions that would be less redundant.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean redundant ? Generics are the only way to specify a dependency between the parameter type and return type `const fn = <T>(a: T) => a; let r= fn(0)` r will be number in the example

Comment: I was referring to something like `fn<number>(0)` as being redundant. I did not know it was possible to extract the generic type from the argument like that. Please add an answer, so I can mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics are the only way to specify a dependency between the parameter type and return type. The good part is you don't have to specify the generic type parameter when calling the function, Typescript will figure it out for you:

```
const fn = <T>(a: T) => a; 
let r= fn(0) // r will be number in the example equivalent to fn<number>(0)
```